# SSMS - connection security

Tags: sql-server, security

This may well be a stupid question, but regardless...

If I use Sql Management Studio to connect to a remote database using a SQL user/password (outside of our network) - how secure is this connection?  Is data encrypted when it is transferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question.

By default, there is no encryption between you and the server. However, you can configure the sql server to accept encrypted connections.

If you've ever set up IIS to use https with a local certificate, the process is very similar. Create a certificate on the server, export the cert to your machine and install. Click connect, select your server, click options and check encrypt connection.

Read more here:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191192.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's kinda what I thought, but my google-fu was bit lacking for finding an answer.